# Outlook profiles keep becoming corrupt when using Google Apps account

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, google-workspace

I'm having a ongoing issue with one of my clients using Google Apps and Outlook. Every now and then it gives me this error:

> Cannot open your default e-mail folders. The information store could not be opened.

The strange thing is that I can open the `.pst` file through Outlook using another profile. I have also found that when this happens, the Google Sync icon isn't running in the system tray. I have to create another profile and sync again to make it work. I have tried `scanpst.exe` as well, to no effect.

Has anyone got a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to create a new Windows profile.

1. reboot the PC
2. log in as an admin (which is not the user having the problems)
3. Move the profile out of the Document and Settings (example to c:\old data)
4. Log in as the user, import your data from the moved profile
5. test again

I've seen many relaated issues like this one because of a corrupt Windows profile. If this works you will want to defrag the system and run "chkdsk c: /f"